# Ruby Find last record value in has many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to find the last Econ_Result that belongs to a Econ_Report. I want to display the last record of the Econ_Result (ordered by "release_date") for each Econ_Report on the index view. In the controller I tried to take the list of all reports and find the last result using the following:

```
@econ_reports = EconReport.all
if @econ_reports.econ_results.size >= 1
  @last_result = @econ_report.econ_results.last.release_date
end
```

`econ_report.econ_results.size` works on the index view when I place it in for each loop. When I try to call the value of the last record I run into issues with the fact that some reports don't yet have results (a temporary issue) so I threw in the if then check in the controller which is currently failing.

Thanks in advance for the rookie help.

Comment: use `@econ_reports.econ_results.count > 1` or `@econ_reports.econ_results.any?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `@econ_reports` is a *collection* of `EconReport` objects, you can't call an instance method like `.econ_results` on it. Instead, you can only call it on instances within the collection:

```
@econ_reports.each do |econ_report|
  if econ_report.econ_results.any?
    last_result = econ_report.econ_results.last
  end
end
```

However, this can be terribly inefficient for a large collection of `@econ_reports`: both lines with `econ_report.econ_results` will query the database separately, meaning that you'll query the database independently for each `econ_report` in the collection. This is known as the [N+1 query problem](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations).

Luckily for you, as discussed in the link, Rails has a built-in solution to optimize this code so you'll only query the database once:

```
<% @econ_reports.includes(:econ_results).each do |econ_report| %>
  <% if econ_report.econ_results.any? %>
    <% last_result = econ_report.econ_results.last %>
    # do something to display last_result
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: it works to a point eirikir. I placed the code in the controller for the econ_reports under index and it does pull up the last value without regard to the specific report record. in other words, the last value was 275,000 which appears on each record in the view instead of just the one record with that as the final value
 To get this to iterate through each report record do I need to place this code elsewhere or do I need to further refine it?

Comment: @M.Wood I'm not sure what you mean. This code will assign `last_result` to the last `econ_result` for *each* `econ_report` – I presumed that you would do something with the `last_result` record *within the block*. Thus, it really works better in the view (see my edit). If that's not what you're looking for, can you be more specific about what you're after, using examples?

Comment: I found my error. Because I am referencing this value in a table of reports I had to reduce the code to exclude the .each do call as it was redundant in the scope of the table. by using

`<% if econ_report.econ_results.any? %>
                  <% last_result = econ_report.econ_results.last %>
              <%= last_result.report_value %>
              <% end %>`

it worked

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the release date you might try:

```
@last_result = @econ_report.econ_results.order('release_date DESC').limit(1).pluck(:release_date).first
```

It's worth noting that a Ruby `if` statement generally looks like:

```
if condition
end
```

The `then` is almost always omitted even though it is allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The solution above works for the show view of the individual report with the variable @econ_report. However, when I try to set the @last_result variable on the index, @econ_report doesn't work (it currently is only set on show, edit, update, destroy) and the variable @econ_reports.econ_results errors out due to the undefined method `econ_results' for nil:NilClass

Comment: to clarify further, it is at the point that I call if @econ_reports.econ_results.size >= 1 that I get the error

Comment: Do you want the last for *each* report, or the last for *all* reports?

Comment: I would like to display the last for each report

Comment: Then you'll need to do this for each one. For example: `@econ_reports.each do |econ_report|` to iterate in your view, then something like what I've suggested for each value.